# Showing one cell at a time for UICollectionView

Tags: xamarin.ios, uicollectionview

I have a collectionview I want to show just one cell at a time and based on my findings on SO it *should* be as simple as setting the item size to the size the collectionview itself but when I did that I see still a small bit of the next cell.

Here is how I've set up my collectionview:

```cs
cvCarousel.RegisterNibForCell(CarouselItemCollectionViewCell.Nib, CarouselItemCollectionViewCell.Key);
cvCarousel.CollectionViewLayout = new UICollectionViewFlowLayout
{
    ItemSize = new CGSize(cvCarousel.Frame.Width, cvCarousel.Frame.Height),
    MinimumInteritemSpacing = 0,
    MinimumLineSpacing = 0,
    ScrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal
};
```

I'm sure there's something simple I'm missing here but not sure what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're calling the following code in `viewDidLoad` method.

Everything will have whatever frame size and position after a while until the layout has been performed, however it is too early in `viewDidLoad` method , we can only get the correct frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method.

However , here you can directly replace `cvCarousel.Frame` with  `UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds` , because you just need a full screen item.

Refer to

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/52578